# MS server 2016 strd mstsc shadow undefined error after Jan update

Tags: rdp, windows-server-2016, mstsc

4x Server 2016 standard edition running as VM's on Hyper-V. None of the Servers are in the domain.
I was using cmd/powershell "mstsc /control /noConsentPrompt /shadow: x"  to shadow **local** users sessions (long since after updating from Server 2008 R2). But right after January update, it doesn't work: "Undefined error" is showing up. The same thing is going on 4 different servers.
And I can't even find what is happening with mstsc in logs. 
Any suggestions? 
Thanks.

Comment: Update 1. I made clean installation of Server 2016 standard with sole RDS role. Updated. Result is the same - RDS shadowing doesn't work. Conclusion - January update destroys it.

Comment: Update 2. Okay. KB4056890 breaks RDS shadowing. There are some threads on github and MS technet. MS made **many** RDS changes. Sad but true. When anyone have the solution, pls post asap.

Comment: Update 3. Uninstalling KB4056890 "solves" the problem for server 2016.

Comment: Update 4. Update KB4057142 solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Clean up your local credential store and check the network connection. I have seen this many, many times and the cause was *always* a 'thing' in the credentail store (just delete the `TERMSRV/*` entry) or a faulty network connection (vmware Tools, NIC driver, Firewall, ...).

Comment: You mean to clear (delete entries) using credential manager? There were no cashed credentials on 2 of 3 servers, cleared on 3th one - no result. And I repeat, there are no domains.
Reinstalled Hyper-V network NIC's - no result.
Is there maybe an mstsc shadowing log or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling KB4056890 "solves" the problem for server 2016.
For now this is the only solution, since MS is ignoring the problem.